# VB.NET - Appending text to the last line of text file leaves (sometimes) an empty line

Tags: vb.net, winforms

The intention of the software I am coding is to append a string to the last line of a text file. The problem I am experiencing is that depending on the situation, sometimes I get an empty line when I try to append text to the last line of a text file.

My text file is very simple. It contains a few lines of text and each line contains a few words. When I open the text file with Windows' Notepad (without editing the content of the text file) and I move the caret to the end of the entire file, sometimes the caret is positioned at the end of the last line with content (text), and sometimes it is positioned at an empty line that doesn't contain even a white space.

When the caret's ending position corresponds to the last char of a line that contains text, I don't experience any problem appending some text programmatically. The programmatically appended line is at a new line and there isn't any empty line between the old last line and the current last line in the text file.

The problem appears when I can move the caret in the text file to the last possible position and that position corresponds to an empty line. In that case, when I try to append a new line programmatically, I can see an empty line before the just added line.

I have tried different codes and techniques, but it always happens the same to me.

The code I am actually using is:

```
If stringLastLine.Length = 0 Then
        Using sw As StreamWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter(filePath, True) 
            sw.Write("Inserted text")
            sw.Close()
        End Using
    ElseIf stringLastLine.Length > 0 Then
        Using sw As StreamWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter(filePath, True) 
            sw.Write(Environment.NewLine & "Inserted text")
            sw.Close()
        End Using
    End If
```

Basically, I am trying to detect if the last line length is over zero, so it's a line with text content and I will use "environment.newline + string". If it's a line without content (length = 0) I add directly the string without using "environment.newline". In the case that length = 0 I always get an empty line in between.

Any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: That stringLastLine variable looks very fishy.  Especially when you don't seem to update it at all in the snippet, even though you should.  It is not going to have the correct value either when you restart the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about trimming your text to ensure there's no end of line characters at the end (the whole text)?  Right now you might have an issue with multiple blank lines:

```
text = text.TrimEnd({Convert.ToChar(10), Convert.ToChar(13)})
```

This handles the EOL characters.

Comment: You could use `vbCr` and `vbLf` instead.

Comment: its the same thing

Comment: Your approach works perfectly. After deleting `Char(10)` and `Char(13)`I have no empty line and I can append a new line of text without generating an empty line.

Comment: glad to hear it